# jade multi level inheritance

Tags: pug, multiple-inheritance

I'm having problems with jade multi level inheritance. My code is on the line of:

layout.jade:

```
head
  block head
    include head
body
  block body
```

index.jade:

```
extends layout
block append body
  block content
include modal1.jade
include modal2.ajde
```

content.jade:

```
extends index
block append head
  script
block content
  p This is my content
```

Them problem I get when I compile this code is that all code included into head from script gets repeated 3 times. Am I doing something wrong here?